# Why does xdx.exe generate string property for xs:nonNegativeInteger?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, xsd.exe

My element:

```
<xs:element name="achats" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" minOccurs="0"/>
```

is generated to:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="nonNegativeInteger")]
public string achats
{
   ...
}
```

Why is this property not generated as an decimal instead of string?
In this doc it should be System.Decimal https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/aa719879(v=vs.71).aspx

XSD is sent by other company, so I can't really modify it. I think I don't use correctly xsd.exe but I don't know how ...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is normal in newer version of .net :

> nonNegativeInteger | String

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx

whereas W3 wrote

> [Definition:]   nonNegativeInteger is ·derived· from **integer** by setting the value of ·minInclusive· to be 0

https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-2-20010502/#nonNegativeInteger